# String items in Variable / Parameter Expansion

Tags: linux, bash, variable-expansion, brace-expansion

I'm trying to use a variable instead of explicitly listing my zone list in multiple places.

I realize that I could just download all of the files, and just apply the ones I'm looking for. I feel like I should be able to do this, and I guess this makes this a bit of an academic exercise. Perhaps my terminology is off, but most of the searching I've done turned up results based on integers. The code below works as is... but i'd like to swap out the `{ru,cn...}` with a `$zone_list` variable. This just as easily could be file extensions or types `{jpg,php,htm,html}` ... am I off base here, or should I be thinking about this another way??

```
#!/bin/bash

ipset=/sbin/ipset
## zone_list="ru,cn,in,hk"
## zone_list="{ru,cn,in,hk}"

## wget -N http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/{$zone_list}.zone -P ~/testing/iptables/blacklists/zones/
wget -N http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/{ru,cn,in,hk}.zone -P ~/testing/iptables/blacklists/zones/

## $ipset -F
## $ipset -N -! blacklist hash:net maxelem 262144

for ip in $(cat ~/testing/iptables/blacklists/zones/{ru,cn,in,hk}.zone); do
   ##  $ipset -A blacklist $ip
   echo $ip
done
```

Edit: Updated script with the answer from Dzienny below

```
#!/bin/bash

ipset=/sbin/ipset
zone_list="{ru,cn,in,hk}"

eval "urls=(http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/${zone_list}.zone)"
wget -N "${urls[@]}" -P /srv/iptables-data/blacklists/zones/

## BLACKZONE RULE (select country to block and ip/range)
## $ipset -F
## $ipset -N -! blacklist hash:net maxelem 262144

eval "zonefiles=(/srv/iptables-data/blacklists/zones/${zone_list}.zone)"
for ip in $(cat "${zonefiles[@]}"); do
   ## $ipset -A blacklist $ip
   echo $ip
done
```

Comment: Your approach sounds sane.  In your first commented wget, you've got `{$zone_list}` instead of `${zone_list}`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I attempted various combinations of `${}` `{$}` `{${}}` and even `eval` embedding the braces in the `zone_list` and not. None of it worked as I had hoped for.

Comment: That should have worked, using the second definition: `zone_list="{ru,cn,in,hk}"`.  It sounds like you're new to shell and don't fully grok shell substitutions.  I suggest making a minimalist script that sets a variable and `echo`s it back out as part of a message.  Experiment to see how it works.  After that, replace the echo with a `for` loop and `echo` it out in pieces, and experiment with quoting in the `for` and the `echo` so you get the sense of how quoting works.  Another shell troubleshooting method is to run a script with `bash -x my_script`, which shows the lines being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bash evaluates](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser) [brace expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) before expanding variables. This means that if you put brace expansion string into a variable and use it, it will not be interpreted, instead the string will stay unchanged.

You could use `eval` builtin to evaluate the content of the variable. Example:

```
zones_exp="{ru,cn,in,hk}"
eval "urls=(http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/${zones_exp}.zone)"
wget -N "${urls[@]}" -P ~/testing/iptables/blacklists/zones/
```

Or you can achieve deduplication of brace expansion by making a helper function, eg:

```
function insert_zones_exp() {
  expansion=("$1"{ru,cn,in,hk}"$2");
}
```

where the first argument is the parth before a zone and the second part after the zone value.

And then using it:

```
insert_zones_exp "http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/" ".zone"
wget -N "${expansion[@]}" -P ~/testing/iptables/blacklists/zones/
```

Comment: This works fantastically for the `wget`, and both approaches effectively do the same thing... expand the strings into another variable, and then reference that variable in the command. Applying this logic to the `cat` for loop, I'm still getting `cat: /home/jason/testing/iptables/blacklists/zones/{ru,cn,in,hk}.zone: No such file or directory`

Comment: my new loop looks like `eval  "zonefiles=~/testing/iptables/blacklists/zones/${zone_list}.zone"`<br/>`for ip in $(cat "${zonefiles[@]}"); do`

Comment: You forgot about `()` to declare the variable as an array. It should be `eval "zonefiles=(~/testing/iptables/blacklists/zones/${zone_list}.zone)"`